# Updating database from multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, sql, database

this is my code for an update button which is supposed to update the database based on entry values of textboxes.I made the textboxes to be filled when user selects a row on datagridview.I want the user to simply click the row then change the textbox texts then click update.But i can't get this to work.All comments are helpful.Shoot.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (txtOgrenciNo.Text.Length != 0 && txtAd.Text.Length != 0 && txtSoyad.Text.Length != 0 && txtEmail.Text.Length != 0 && txtTelefon.Text.Length != 0)
            {
                string query ="UPDATE ogrenci(studentId,name,lname,email,phone) SET (studentId=@studentId,name@name,lname=@lname,email=@email,phone=@phone) WHERE studentId=@studentId";
                string query1 = "UPDATE loginusers(username,upassword) SET (username=@email,upassword=@phone) WHERE username=@email";
                using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailVal", txtEmail.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", txtPhone.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentId", txtStudentId.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtLname.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", txtPhone.Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    populateGrid();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Student Information can not be blank","Alert",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter different student info", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

Comment: because you must execute queries one by one

Comment: i use a similar code for add button which has INSERT instead of UPDATE in queries and it works perfectly.

Comment: and I think when you insert there is only one query? Am I right?

Comment: Seems that you don't provide parameters under this block: `using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))`. SQL queries requires parameter for each execution even the parameters are same, and should be evaluated one-by-one.

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev there ıs two queries one for students and one for loginusers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `update` queries, remove `(parameters)` after `table name`

Change this lines

```
string query ="UPDATE ogrenci(studentId,name,lname,email,phone) SET (studentId=@studentId,name@name,lname=@lname,email=@email,phone=@phone) WHERE studentId=@studentId";
string query1 = "UPDATE loginusers(username,upassword) SET (username=@email,upassword=@phone) WHERE username=@email";
```

To this

```
string query ="UPDATE ogrenci SET  studentId=@studentId,name@name,lname=@lname,email=@email,phone=@phone WHERE studentId=@studentId";
string query1 = "UPDATE loginusers SET username=@email,upassword=@phone WHERE username=@email";
```

Comment: one more question i can update name lname email but when i try to update phone number it conflicts with the foreign key it says do you know a way around this ?

Comment: Your phone column references primary key column on another table, so your new updated value should exist on another table, if not it raises error you show. For more info look this - [Foreign Keys Oluşturma](http://www.ismailgursoy.com.tr/foreign-keys-olusturma/)